# JavaScript quotation marks change after echo

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
$t="<table>
      <tr>
        <td >
           <a  href='#' onClick='alert('some text!');'  >
        </td>

      </tr>
      <table>";

echo $t;
```

any inline javascript didn't work so I inspect the a element in browser and turns out its like:

```
<a  href="#" onClick="alert("some text');'>
```

What am I doing wrong with quotation marks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
$t=<<<EOT
<table>
      <tr>
        <td >
           <a  href='#' onClick='alert("some text!");'  >
        </td>

      </tr>
<table>
EOT;
```

or

```
$t="
<table>
      <tr>
        <td >
           <a  href='#' onClick='alert(\"some text!\");'  >
        </td>

      </tr>
<table>
";
```

echo $t;

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$t="<table>
      <tr>
        <td >
           <a  href='#' onClick=\"alert('some text!');\"  >test</a>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <table>";

echo $t;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You got wrong quotes. Try this:

```
<a href='#' onclick=\"alert('some text!');\">
```

Comment: this is how you would do for HTML within PHP double-quoted string

Answer (score 0):

```
<a  href='#' onClick=\"alert('some text!');\">
```

Use this code this will work fine.